# Error expected : Ternary conditional nil for not optional type of parameter in SwiftUI function

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Code below works fine even if optional type isn't what the `.gesture()` modifier really wants for its parameter type.

```
someKindOfView
    .gesture(condition ? DragGesture() : nil)
```

Why is this possible?

Many thanks!!!!

Comment: Your question is different from your description. Please review your question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `Gesture` is generic protocol...

[image: demo1]

and so the `gesture` modifier accepts generic type conforming to `Gesture`

[image: demo2]

and there is such extension confirming `Optional` to `Gesture`

[image: demo3]

so in case of

```
.gesture(condition ? DragGesture() : nil)
```

compiler infers type as `.gesture(_ gesture: DragGesture?, ...` and all works.